# I cannot understand this error in XHTML strict

Tags: php, html, xhtml-1.0-strict, xhtml

This page is generated through a PHP script. Here is the error message:

> Line 14, Column 8: end tag for "tbody"
>   which is not finished
>
> ```
> </tbody></table>
> ```
>
> Most likely, you nested tags and
>   closed them in the wrong order. For
>   example `<p><em>...</p>` is not
>   acceptable, as `<em>` must be closed
>   before `<p>`. Acceptable nesting is:
>   `<p><em>...</em></p>`
>
> Another possibility is that you used
>   an element which requires a child
>   element that you did not include.
>   Hence the parent element is "not
>   finished", not complete. For instance,
>   in HTML the `<head>` element must
>   contain a `<title>` child element, lists
>   require appropriate list items (`<ul>`
>   and `<ol>` require `<li>`; 
>   requires `<dt>` and `<dd>`), and so
>   on.

Here is what my code looks like when you view source in Google Chrome:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title></title> 
    <link href="CSS/Index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h3>Search Results</h3> 
<table> 
<tbody> 
</tbody></table> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Here is what my code looks like when you view source in Firefox:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>PcDescribeTable</title>
<link href="CSS/Index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body>
<h3>Search Results</h3>
<table>
<tr><td>Intel i7-950 3.06GHz</td></tr>
<tr><td>WD 500GB 7200RPM SATA 6GBs</td></tr>
<tr><td>XFX Radeon HD 6870</td></tr>
<tr><td>CORSAIR 4GB DDR3 1600</td></tr>
<tr><td>ASUS P6X58D-E LGA 1366</td></tr>
<tr><td>CORSAIR Enthusiast Series 650W</td></tr>
<tr><td>VisonTek Bigfoot Killer</td></tr>
<tr><td>Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi HD</td></tr>
<tr><td>Razer Lycrosa</td></tr>
<tr><td>24x DVD Burner</td></tr>
<tr><td>Asus 23" Full HD LED</td></tr>
<tr><td>Razer Death Adder</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what the Php Script looks like:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<?php
for ( $counter = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_row( $result ); $counter++ )
{
print("<tr>");
foreach ( $row as $key => $value )
print( "<td>".$value."</td>");
print("</tr>");
}
print("</tbody>");
print("</table>");
mysql_close($database);
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not passing validation because you've got nothing in your TBODY. Add some rows with columns and it'll validate.

Comment: There is content in the table, that was my view source on Google Chrome, i don't know why it took my content out in the view source, but in Firefox it shows my content, I'll edit my question to show the Firefox Source as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that for loop will work. Plus, you don't appear to use `$counter` for anything. Try while instead:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $result ) )
```

If that still doesn't echo anything, you probably don't have any rows to fetch to begin with. So nothing is output between your `<tbody>` tags, and an empty `<tbody>` is considered invalid XHTML.

Comment: @BoltClock Here's where the weird thing happens, The source code says there is nothing in the table. but the table is correctly populating, which is why I don't understand the error, I should have probably put that in the question as well.

Comment: The query must be depending on POST data, therefore returning nothing when accessed by Google Chrome or the validator. After all, neighter Google Chrome nor W3C sends post data when downloading the source.

Comment: @ksiegel So then I should have it GET data instead of post it?, What is extremely confusing about this, is I have this same code practically with the only change is the Query, and the Code validates.

Comment: @Donnie: Not necessarily; instead simply validate using a different browser.

Comment: @BoltClock , Ran the validator in Firefox and IE, still have the same exact error

Answer (score 0):

Only include the table at all if there are rows in it. If you provided more of the php script, an if statement should easily exclude them and allow it to validate.

**EDIT:** I did not understand your question completely till I saw a comment on another solution.

What's happening here is your query is depending on POST data, or cookies, or some sort of data that is not being passed by the validator. The solution could be to have a default value in your query in case one is not sent. You could also chop out the table all together, as I originally said, if there is no post data sent.

Comment: how can this same code run on a different page and validate then? I could have the data just post out as one giant string I suppose :) but it just really confused me at how it does validate for one page, but not the next.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right and the HTML generated looks right, but I assume that the mysql_fetch_row returns something.  Is it possible that this is sending something that looks like an HTML tag?

That's where I'd start looking.  Confirm that the syntax is right for the PHP and is returning what you expect.

Comment: @user650933, the mysql is returning the expected values

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP, use an if statement to test if a query has been sent. If not, don't even print the table out to the screen.

```
<?php
if (mysql_fetch_row( $result )) {
?>
<table>
<tbody>
<?php
for ( $counter = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_row( $result ); $counter++ ) {
print("<tr>");
foreach ( $row as $key => $value )
print( "<td>".$value."</td>");
print("</tr>");
}
mysql_close($database);
?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: It prints out to the screen, For some reason Google Chrome and the Validator are showing it as an empty table, but there is information in it, I copied the source code from FireFox as well, to show that FireFox is showing that the table is validated.

Comment: Hmm, can you try directly accessing the page, without sending the POST request? What I'm trying to do is test if `$result` or `mysql_fetch_row( $result )` exists.